# Linux - How to execute a command in root and display the result to user during login

Tags: linux, unix, suse

I have some core dump files in a specific path/corefiles (SUSE10 OS) created by many users.

So during any user login I want to execute a command in root which checks any coredump files created by this logging user and those file names should be displayed to the user, (similar to welcome message)

Note: I don't want to add any commands in .bshrc or .cshrc etc files which are specific to user login. because there are huge number of users in my machine and useradd and userdel may happen dynamically anytime.

**Any suggestion how it can be done ..?**
Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean i need to run a script in root (in background), which suggest users about coredump files during user login.

Comment: "in root (in background)". This combination of words makes no sense. Explain what you mean, preferably by pointing at relevant documentation.

Comment: its simple,, script runs in root and displays coredump file info to the users as welcome message during users login,

Comment: You can modify /etc/profile to run a script for all users.

Comment: You keep using these words "in root". I have no idea what you mean. If you mean "as root", root being the privileged user, then the question is why do you want it. If you mean something else, please feel free to explain using any available source of information. Meanwhile, closing as unclear.

Comment: yes,, login as a root, i need to run a command (or script) as root user which checks dump file in fixed path, and displays the file details to the particular user who created dump file. (Display should be during user login which is similar to welcome message).. I hope my question is clear now

Comment: If the user can see and manipulate the file, the command can provide details about it without being run as root. If the user cannot see and manipulate the file, any details the program might provide are useless.

Comment: If the program should first check all the files for all users, and then at a separate step present to each user only files that belong to him, then  you might be on to something. The step of checking is independent from any user being logged in. Run the checking script as a cron job periodically, have it generate a report for each user and put it in a place accessible to that user. The step of presenting the results to the user should be executed as that user, not as root, at login time.

Comment: For the presentation you may add a call to a presentation script to /etc/profile (or as a file to /etc/profile.d/ if your system uses it).  Or you can add `pam_exec` to the list of PAM modules for your users and give it your presentation script.